# django authenticate() for custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Below is my custom user model:

```
 class CUserManager(BaseUserManager):

        def _create_user(self, email, first_name, password,
                         is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
            """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          first_name = first_name,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=False,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)


class CUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

It creates a new user correctly. But when I try to authenticate the user from shell or from views, the authenticate() function doesn't work for users having `is_active=False`.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, auhtenticate
>>> u = get_user_model()
>>> authenticate(username='abc@gmail.com', password='abc)
```

The above line returns nothing if the user is inactive but returns the user object otherwise.
I don't understand why its returning nothing for inactive users.

Comment: Because that's the whole point of marking users as inactive, surely. You can't log in if your account is not active.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because of how django's authentication works. [By default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS) it uses `ModelBackend` which checks for `is_active` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.get_user_permissions

So you can create custom authentication backend which will ignore this option
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can write Custom backend for this problem.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password 

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from apps.staffs.models import Staff(Custom User)


class StaffBackend:

    # Create an authentication method
    # This is called by the standard Django login procedure
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            # Try to find a user matching your username
            user = Staff.objects.get(username=username)

            #  Check the password is the reverse of the username
            if check_password(password, user.password):
                # Yes? return the Django user object
                return user
            else:
                # No? return None - triggers default login failed
                return None
        except Staff.DoesNotExist:
            # No user was found, return None - triggers default login failed
            return None

    # Required for your backend to work properly - unchanged in most scenarios
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Staff.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except Staff.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

There are standard methods of doing it by customizing the auth backend. Some of them feel too cumbersome for simple applications that are to be done within deadlines. Here is a customized function that addresses this issue:

### Code

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

from users.models import CustomUser


def authenticate(username=None, password=None):
    try:
        # Get the corresponding user.
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        #  If password, matches just return the user. Otherwise, return None.
        if check_password(password, user.password):
            return user
        return None
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        # No user was found.
        return None
```

### Explanation

- This returns a User object if the given user with matching username and password is found.
- The `username` parameter can be switched with any other parameter as well - like `email`, et cetera, whatever the logic needs.
- Custom Model `Manager`s are not needed here.

### Where and How to Use?

I have a special `helper.py` file within each app to have such functions or classes. So that's where this goes. Just import it and use `authenticate()` the usual way, except this would now work on the `CustomUser` model rather than the `User` model.